# Automatically generate unique type ID and vice versa

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

[Regarding to this code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/44941), is it possible to also assign a `size_t` to a type? i.e.:

```
template <size_t N>
struct IntToType {
    typedef ??? type; // ???
};

TypeID::value<int>();               // "assigns" 0 to int
IDType<0>::type;                    // resolves to int
TypeID::value<IDType<0>::type>();   // resolves to 0
```

I think it's just impossible by language design, this kind of recursion is probably impossible because it may depend on the order the code is being compiled, but I'll ask anyway.

It's ok to have any other way of defining an unique ID for each type if the other way around works.

Comment: Even if there are ways to do this - I suspect that Filip Roséen's "stateful metaprogramming" technique might be able to accomplish something like this - the committee is planning on banning it, so there's not that much point.

Comment: Did you consider using `std::type_index`? (But to be honest I'm not sure what your question)

Comment: @T.C. 's answer is the one, I would accept it. So ok, it's possible maybe, but will be banned. Fine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a templates expert by any means, so I don't know of any loopholes in this, but it seems you could hard-wire type info using *template specializations* as follows:

```
template <typename T>
struct TypeId {
};

template <>
struct TypeId<int> {
    static const size_t value = 0;
};

template <>
struct TypeId<unsigned> {
    static const size_t value = 1;
};

template <>
struct TypeId<long> {
    static const size_t value = 2;
};

template <>
struct TypeId<unsigned long> {
    static const size_t value = 3;
};

template <>
struct TypeId<float> {
    static const size_t value = 4;
};

template <>
struct TypeId<double> {
    static const size_t value = 5;
};

// ------

template <size_t N>
struct TypeInfo {
};

template <>
struct TypeInfo<TypeId<int>::value> {
    typedef int type;
    static constexpr char const* name = "int";
};

template <>
struct TypeInfo<TypeId<unsigned>::value> {
    typedef unsigned type;
    static constexpr char const* name = "unsigned int";
};

template <>
struct TypeInfo<TypeId<long>::value> {
    typedef long type;
    static constexpr char const* name = "long int";
};

template <>
struct TypeInfo<TypeId<unsigned long>::value> {
    typedef unsigned long type;
    static constexpr char const* name = "unsigned long int";
};

template <>
struct TypeInfo<TypeId<float>::value> {
    typedef float type;
    static constexpr char const* name = "float";
};

template <>
struct TypeInfo<TypeId<double>::value> {
    typedef double type;
    static constexpr char const* name = "double";
};

// ---

void func(int i)
{
    std::cout << "func int\n";
    std::cout << TypeInfo<TypeId<decltype(i)>::value>::name << '\n';
}

void func(float f)
{
    std::cout << "func float\n";
    std::cout << TypeInfo<TypeId<decltype(f)>::value>::name << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    TypeInfo<0>::type n1 = {};
    TypeInfo<4>::type n2 = {};

    func(n1);
    func(n2);

    std::cout << TypeInfo<TypeId<int>::value>::name << ": " << TypeId<int>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << TypeInfo<TypeId<unsigned>::value>::name << ": " << TypeId<unsigned>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << TypeInfo<TypeId<double>::value>::name << ": " << TypeId<double>::value << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
func int
int
func float
float
int: 0
unsigned int: 1
double: 5
```

Comment: I meant to do it **automatically**. At the code review, the size_t assignation is being done automatically by the compiler, but not hard wired.

Comment: @alesegdia Ah well, I had fun playing with it anyway.;)